# Pass simple function directly to es6 promise.then

Tags: javascript, callback, es6-promise

I have the following ES6 chain of promises in an express route function (i.e. res is the express response object).  findQnameForId is a Promise, and mongoDelete and mysqlDelete both return Promises. The chain works when I use the code commented out instead the current last line, but my question is why can't I pass res.send to `then` directly (as shown) and have it return then's result back to the client?

```
findQnameForId
.then(mongoDelete)
.then(mysqlDelete)
.then(res.send, res.status(400).send);
// .then(function(result) {
//  res.send(result);
// })
// .catch(function(err) {
//  res.status(400).send(err);
// });
```

Comment: Use arrow functions: `.then(() => res.send(), err => res.status(400).send(err))` It's what they're for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect it has to do with not having the correct `this` value during the callbacks. It might work with `bind`:

```
var fourhundred = res.status(400);
findQnameForId
.then(mongoDelete)
.then(mysqlDelete)
.then(res.send.bind(res), fourhundred.send.bind(fourhundred));
```

...but keep reading.

If you know for sure that `res.status(400)` returns `res`, then it's a bit simpler:

```
findQnameForId
.then(mongoDelete)
.then(mysqlDelete)
.then(res.send.bind(res), res.status(400).send.bind(res));
```

...but keep reading.

Note that in either case you're calling `res.status(400)` even on success (before you call `then`), which is probably not what you want. So you probably need a middle ground:

```
findQnameForId
.then(mongoDelete)
.then(mysqlDelete)
.then(res.send.bind(res), function(err) {
    res.status(400).send(err));
});
```

That way, you only call `res.success(400)` if an error occurs.

Comment: Thanks, although I ended up need to use `.then(res.status(200).send.bind(res),...` - not sure why the default 200 was not used in this instance. The wonders of `this`!

Comment: @SimonH: Glad to help. But if you have `.then(res.status(200).send.bind(res), res.status(400).send.bind(res))` beware that you're calling `res.status(200)`, then `.bind(res)`, then `res.status(400)`, then `.bind(res)`, then `.then`. Which means the last call to `status` will be with the value 400. But if you're doing what I did at the end of the answer, then the `status(400)` will only happen in the error case and you're in good shape. :-)

Comment: Not sure whether it was luck or judgement but I used your final snippet with the `status(200)` addition. Thanks for your help